# Apple IOs update, will old version remain?

Tags: ios, updates

I have a question,

If I update my app to a newer version and the update won't be accepted, will the old one still stay available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your old version will stay live if your update is rejected. So don't worry!

Comment: Okay, great! Could you tell me where you got this information? I've been searching for a while now and couldn't find it anywhere...

Comment: I don't believe it's written down anywhere, but I can confirm that in my personal experience (20+ apps) this has been the case.